# Using next style in InDesign table cells

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, tables, cell

One of the coolest features that InDesign incorporated, Imho, is the next style (in paragraph styles). Nevertheless, I came across an issue where I'm not sure if my process is wrong, a glitch, or a feature that have not been incorporated yet.

For the record, I am using InDesign CC 2017.

I setup a table style that incorporates a header cell style and a body cell style. The body uses a paragraph style that was set with a 'next style' in order to change the style for the next paragraph within the same cell.

Now here is my problem, it doesn't work as intended. It only applies the initial paragraph style throughout the body cells.

I have already cleared all types of styles that was applied to the table, its cells and content; then I reapplied the table style, but to no avail.

Is there something that I might be missing? is there a workaround that I can incorporate? Any feedback is very much appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure: you are applying the body cell style by right-clicking and choosing “Apply Style, Then Next Style” (or however exactly it goes)? Not just letting the table automatically apply the style? The next style set in a paragraph style is only applied to new text or manually, but I’m assuming you probably know that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - It doesn't matter what I use, if I apply the table style as a whole or the cell style to the row, it still would not utilize the 'next style' feature set in the paragraph style; it ignores it.

Comment: Yes, if you just apply the style, it applies the style you choose to all the selected text. That’s how paragraph styles work. It does that with regular text as well. If you want it to use the next style feature, you have to select all the text you want to format, then _right-click_ on the style in question and choose “Apply [style] then Next Style”. That’s the only way to apply the next style feature to already existing text. It only automatically applies it when you’re typing and you hit enter to start a new paragraph.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet unfortunately that doesn't work either. The only way to utilize the 'next style' feature is through object styles (given that you have a few paragraphs). It will not however work on tables, even with object styles applied. It totally ignores it. I hope there is a workaround or some script to utilize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Paragraph Next Style** feature only works with **Object Styles** as it is explained at the second part of this answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/110987/120647

For having different paragraph styles in a Table, you should create a Table Style with the corresponding Cell Styles and each Cell Style with a Paragraph Style.

Another option is to find a GREP Style solution to the min Paragraph Style.