# text on different lines with different styles, colours, leading and baseline shift, can it be turned into a paragraph style?

Tags: adobe-indesign, batch-processing, typesetting, grep, publishing

I have a text box with text on different lines with different styles, colors, leading and baseline shift. Is it possible to create this as a "standard/ master version", so that whenever any information is copied in from my body copy it can immediately take this form and set up?

I am creating a catalog and have each products information in a separate document. I just want to copy it all into my catalog and then apply this style to each separate text box. Is this possible without going into a script?[image]

Comment: I would use next styles for blocks of repeated styles. Its a bit complicated to explain, but there's tons of videos about this. And @Danielillo's answer below seems to cover this.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities:

- **Grep Styles**
- **Object Styles**

[image: grepStyle]

**Grep Styles**

Character Styles:

- *Blue Text*
- *Red Text*
- *Bold Text*

Paragraph Style:

- *Label Text*: the paragraph style is the one of the last text (30-38) or the most repetitive

[image: styles]

And those are the Greps:

[image: greps]

The first one is for the *Blue Text*
`^[\l\u]+(?!/)\r` and means every letter and the following between the beginning and the end of a paragraph, excepting those with a `/`

**Object Styles**

This is more useful in case that some of the text lines has not a possible Grep, for example if the colors never has a `/` character.
[image: object style]

At the **Object Style Options** window > **Paragraph Styles** > assign a **Paragraph Style** and check **Apply Next Style**

[image: object style options]

In this case just two paragraph styles: the *Blue Text* with a **Next Style** *Regular Text* which has as a **Grep Style** *Red Text* and *Bold Text*. With this option you can link Paragraph Styles to infinity if the next style from the origin has another next style attached.

[image: blue text]

Having either of these two options, it is possible after pasting all the text, do a general find/change to apply the desired style.